# Swift: Adding a method to viewDidLoad on assignment of UIHostingController

Tags: ios, swift

How do I assign override methods on a UIHostingControllers viewDidLoad?

```
  let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: View1(viewModel: VM()))
      vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
      vc.viewDidLoad() {
         override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
            return true
         }
   }
```

I know that "vc.viewDidLoad()" is incorrect but that is the idea I am going for.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You'd need to subclass `UIHostingController`

Comment: Gah, no other way around this?

Comment: Not that I know of. But it's not a big task -- you've basically written all the code already! It just needs to be reorganized slightly.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you. I think I was overthinking the complication haha